# on layout Change Lisnter error

Tags: android

What is the wrong with this code?

row_height gives a value outside `onLayoutChange`* but gives zero inside `CreateEvent`

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int row_height;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);
    textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            row_height = bottom - top;
            textView.setText("" + row_height); //this show a correct value
        }
    });
    float Start_time = (float) 6;
    int Event_duration_in_min = 120;
    int day_number = 3;
    CreateEvent(Event_duration_in_min, Start_time, day_number - 1);
}

private void CreateEvent(final int event_duration_in_min, final float start_time, final int day) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);
    textView.setText("" + row_height); // this show 0 !!
    }
}
```

---

how to fix this ?

---

```
 private void CreateEvent(final int event_duration_in_min, final float start_time, final int day) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView27);//any textview from the horizontal grid
    textView.setText("" + row_height);
    //Now creating events here
    textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);

            final int width = right - left;
            float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;//const code line
            int pixels_h = (int) (event_duration_in_min * scale + 0.5f);//const code line

            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplication().getApplicationContext());
            if(row_height == 120) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, pixels_h * 2);//const code line
                tv.setLayoutParams(Params1);

            }
            else {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, pixels_h);//const code line
                tv.setLayoutParams(Params1);

            }

            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
            tv.setText("attttttttef");

            tv.setX(day * width);

            tv.setY((float) (start_time * row_height));
            RL.addView(tv);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `layout` for your view has not occurred by the time you call `CreateEvent()`, so the height will be zero.  If you want to call `CreateEvent()` once your `row_height` is determined, put it inside your `OnLayoutChangeListener`, and check that your `row_height` is greater than zero.

Comment: This is helpful, however the 'CreateEvent' is now not giving me the expected result, nothing from the code inside works now
please check the edit to know the code of  'CreateEvent' i

Comment: You've already added a `OnLayoutChangeListener` in `onCreate`, you shouldn't need another one in the `CreateEvent` method. Just call your `CreateEvent` from within the `OnLayoutChangeListener`.

Comment: No, I am determining the height of the `daynamic textview` `tv` depending on height of `textview33` (that is what i did in `oncreate`) then i determine the width of it depending on width of `textview27`

Comment: I would then look into using [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) instead, registered to the parent view for the 2 `TextView`s you're using. This will trigger a callback when the layout of the root view has changed (and you should be able to get the height/width of both `TextView`s then).

Comment: Thank you very much, u r great Mr/ Alex

Answer (score 0):

Based on your result, CreateEvent is called before the OnLyoutChangeListener is triggered. Therefore, textView27's text is set before the row_height is assigned in the onLayoutChange (default 0).

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your CreateEvent method to receive the row_height as a parameter and change this line to:

`CreateEvent(Event_duration_in_min, Start_time, day_number - 1, row_height);`